# Duplicate values from csv are inserted to DB using Apache Camel

Tags: csv, apache-camel

I have a large chunk of CSV files(Each containing around millions of records).
So I use seda to use the multi-threading feature. I split 50000 in chunks, process it and get a List of Entity objects, which I want to split and persist to DB using jpa. Initially I was getting a Out of Heap Memory Exception. But later I used a high configuration system and Heap issue was solved.

But right now the issue is, I am getting duplicate records getting inserted in the DB. say if there are 1000000 records in the csv, around 2000000 records are getting inserted to DB.
There is no primary key for the records in the Csv files. So I have used hibernate to generate a primary key for it.

Below is my code (came-context.xml)

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file:C:\Users\PPP\Desktop\input?noop=true" />
            <to uri="seda:StageIt" />
        </route>


        <route>
            <from uri="seda:StageIt?concurrentConsumers=1" />
            <split streaming="true">
                <tokenize token="\n" group="50000"></tokenize>
                <to uri="seda:WriteToFile" />
            </split>
        </route>


        <route>
            <from uri="seda:WriteToFile?concurrentConsumers=8" />

            <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                <simple>${exchangeId}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <unmarshal ref="bindyDataformat">
                <bindy type="Csv"  classType="target.bindy.RealEstate"  />
            </unmarshal>
            <split>
                <simple>body</simple>
                <to uri="jpa:target.bindy.RealEstate"/>
            </split>
</route>
```

Please Help.

Comment: _"Is my code correct"_ -- we don't know since you have not provided any information about what "correct" is in your particular situation.

Comment: Hi Jim, I am talking about the camel-context.xml. Is there any other piece of code you want from my side?

Comment: Please post the mappings for `RealEstate` entity.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be accidently starting 2 contexts up so the routes run twice? If How  do you start the route?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be with "?noop=true". Since this doesn't move the file that is being processed. As a result, Camel will consume the file again and again. Have you tried removing this option so Camel would move this file to a .camel subdirectory? Camel by default doesn't process files that are in a "hidden" directory -the ones that start with DOT. You can also add "?moveFailed=.failed" as a precaution, so files will be always moved to a directory, even if they fail. Let me know if this helps.

R.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the duplicates in the DB, you could create the primary key from a hash of a record's contents instead of using hibernate to generate a random one.

Comment: I could have done that but just wanted to know why camel is inserting duplicate records. As there are no duplicates in the csv file. Camel is inserting a single record several times.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why that is happening

Answer (score 0):

add this  noop.flag: true, to yml file,  it will flag a file that camel process and will not process it again, also you can specify a destination location as soon as d file is processed, it moves a copy, then you do a manual delete method to remove the processed files from the source folder. a scheduler will be best to achieve it